# Grails controller not returning JSON in integration testing

Tags: json, grails, groovy, spock

I've got a controller defined:

```
class FamilyController extends RestfulController {
    def springSecurityService
    def familyService

    static responseFormats = ['json']

    FamilyController() {
        super(Family)
    }

    @Override
    protected List<Family> listAllResources(Map params) {
        def user = springSecurityService.loadCurrentUser()
        return Family.findAllByUser(user)
    }

    @Override
    protected Family createResource() {
        //def instance = super.createResource()
        //TODO: Should be able to run the above line but there is an issue GRAILS-10411 that prevents it.
        // Code from parent is below, as soon as the jira is fixed, remove the following lines:

        def p1 = params
        def p2 = getObjectToBind()

        Family instance = resource.newInstance()
        bindData instance, getObjectToBind()

        /*
         * In unit testing, the bindData operation correctly binds the params
         * data to instance properties.  When running with integration tests,
         * this doesn't happen and I have to do the property assignment myself.
         * Not sure if this breaks anything elsewhere.
         */

        instance.properties = p1

        //Code from super ends here

        familyService.addFamilyToUser(instance)

        return instance
    }

    @Override
    protected Family queryForResource(Serializable id) {
        def inst = familyService.safeGetFamily(Long.parseLong(id))

        return inst
    }

    public create()
    {
        Family r = this.createResource()

        render r as JSON
    }

    public index()
    {
        render this.listAllResources(params) as JSON
    }
}
```

And for pedantic purposes (I'm new to grails/groovy and I want to watch the controller work), I want to take a look at actual results from the various actions in the controller.  So I built an integration test:

```
@Mock([AdultPlanning, Primary, Secondary, Child, Family, Tenant, User])
class FamilyControllerIntegrationSpec extends IntegrationSpec {

    Tenant tenant
    User user
    FamilyController controller = new FamilyController()
    FamilyService familyService = new FamilyService()

    def setupSpec() {
        tenant = new Tenant(name: 'MMSS')
        user = new User(subject: "What is a subject?", identityProvider: "http://google.com/")

        tenant.addToUsers(user)
        tenant.save()
        user.save() // The tenant save should propagate to the user, this is to make sure.

        /*
         * Set up the custom marshalling code for family objects.
         */

        new AdultPlanningMarshaller()
        new ChildMarshaller()
        new FamilyMarshaller()
        new FamilyTypeEnumMarshaller()

        return
    }

    def cleanup() {
    }

    void "Create a Family"() {
        when:
        def mSpringSecurityService = mockFor(SpringSecurityService)

        /*
         * I expect to make n calls (1..3) on loadCurrentUser in this test.
         */

        mSpringSecurityService.demand.loadCurrentUser(1..3) { -> return user }
        controller.springSecurityService = mSpringSecurityService.createMock()

        controller.request.contentType = 'text/json'

        controller.index()

        def json

        try {
            json = controller.response.json
        }
        catch (e)
        {
            json = null // action didn't emit any json
        }
        def text = controller.response.text

        then:
        !json
        text == "[]"

        when:
        controller.params.name = "Test"
        controller.params.typeOfFamily = FamilyTypeEnum.SINGLE

        controller.familyService.springSecurityService = controller.springSecurityService //mSpringSecurityService.createMock()

        /*
         * I've tried both GET (default) and POST to get bindData to pick up parameters properly,
         * with no joy.
         */

//        controller.request.method = "POST"
        controller.request.contentType = 'text/json'

        controller.create()

        try {
            json = controller.response.json
        }
        catch (e)
        {
            json = null // action didn't emit any json
        }
        text = controller.response.text

        then:
        1 == 1

        when:
        controller.index()
        json = controller.response.json

        then:
        json.name == "Test"
    }
}
```

So in the first when block, I get no families listed (and empty json object and a string of [] in the response), which I expected, but until I actually implemented the index action in code, I got no json back from the action which I didn't expect.

On to the 2nd when.  I create a family (problems there with dataBinding but I tossed in a workaround, first things first) and the family gets created and saved, but nothing comes back in the response.  I've used the debugger and I see the JSON marshaller triggering for the newly created family so SOMETHING is rendering JSON but where is it going?.

So I'm clearly doing something wrong (or I don't understand what actions are supposed to do in terms of what they return for passing on to the web client) but I'm new in this domain and don't have a clue as to what was done wrong.

Comment: The documentation on integration testing shows that instead of using the provided "controller", you should instantiate your own instace (eg. def fc = new FamilyController()) and call the response on that which is automatically added. I'm not sure if that might help? Also when parsing JSON we've used controllerInstance.response.contentAsString so that might be worth a try also?

Comment: For integration tests you shouldn't be mocking anything. Can you specify the grails version? It looks like you're using grails 2.X